# BufferedReader input while reading from file always null in while loop

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a text file and create an array. Setting the array with the first 2 values of the file which appear on the first line. Then adding all remaining items in file to the array. My array is also always null for some reason. What corrections would need to be made for this to function properly?

```
public static Grid createGrid(String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input;
        String inputLine;
        char[][] grid;
        Grid currentGrid;
        int currentLine = 0;
        try{
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            inputLine = input.readLine();
            String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
            if(tokens.length != 2){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            int height = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            int width = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            grid = new char[height][width];
            while(inputLine != null){ // Giving me (Condition 'inputLine != null' is always 'true') in ide
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                inputLine = input.readLine();
                for(int i = 0; i < inputLine.length() - 1; i++){
                    char currentGem = inputLine.charAt(i);
                    grid[currentLine][i] = currentGem;
                }
                currentLine++;
            }
            input.close();
            currentGrid = new Grid(grid);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            currentGrid = null;
        }
        return currentGrid; // Giving me (Value 'currentGrid' is always 'null') in ide
    }
```

Comment: Title is misleading if "BufferedReader input ... always null" how does `inputLine.split(" ")` not throw an exception?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thanks for pointing that out will correct it

Comment: and are you not getting any `NullPointerException` at the end of the file?? most always have an (additional) `e.printStackTrace()` inside any `catch` block - that is why you don't *see* the exception, just printing the message can be confusing (cause of exception here is that the return of `readLine` is not being checked against null **before** processing)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Not getting any other errors in my code other than the 2 spots noted. Cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger 4 2
y 0
r 1
yr
b 0
y 1
by
b 0
b 1
bb
r 0
r 1
rr
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Grid.createGrid(Grid.java:35)
 at TestPhase2.main(TestPhase2.java:7)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger this is where I am getting nullPointerException, so it is reading all my values into the array correctly but then is giving the error in the for loop after all values have been read.

Comment: sure is, as I already wrote: " the return of readLine is not being checked against null **before** processing" , see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58497537/85421) below - Having an Exception should be part of the question, kind of important source for solving most problems...

Comment: Your loop should read `while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null)`, with no other `readLine()` calls inside it.

Comment: @user207421 that solved it

Answer (score -1):

In your code ...

> while(inputLine != null)

... will always be `true` because `inputLine` is your `String` and it will always have a value when this check is run. The reason is because once you read a `null` into `inputLine` (when you reach the end of your file), instead of running the loop check, you'll have a `NullPointerException` thrown the moment you try run the next line of code...  `for(int i = 0; i < inputLine.length() - 1; i++)`. This in turn will result in `currentGrid` always being `null` as it's still declared as `null` at that point.

To fix this you simply need to add a `inputLine = input.readLine();` before your `while` and then move that same line in your `while` to the end of the `while`, as follows...

```
public static Grid createGrid(String filename) throws IOException {
    Grid currentGrid = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String inputLine = input.readLine();
        String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
        if(tokens.length != 2){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int height = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        int width = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        char[][] grid = new char[height][width];
        int currentLine = 0;
        inputLine = input.readLine(); // added before while
        while(inputLine != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            for(int i = 0; i < inputLine.length() - 1; i++){
                char currentGem = inputLine.charAt(i);
                grid[currentLine][i] = currentGem;
            }
            currentLine++;
            inputLine = input.readLine(); // last line in while
        }
        input.close();
        currentGrid = new Grid(grid);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        currentGrid = null;
    }
    return currentGrid; 
}
```

Oh, you'll also noticed I moved your declarations around. You do not been to declare `BufferedReader input`, `String inputLine` and `char[][] grid` outside your `try { ... } catch` block. Also you only need to declare `int currentLine = 0;` just before you need it (it's just good practice).

Comment: at first I thought so, but `catch (IOException ex)` will **not** be triggered by NPE.... this must be happening somewhere else. Hint: the reading can be done as `while ((inputLine  = input.readLine()) != null) {` avoiding repetition

Comment: This fixed the errors I was having with that and they no longer appear in my ide, but still getting nullPointerException, as mentioned previously.

Comment: @ic0n Add the NullPointerException to your catch and see which line number the exception is being thrown on.

Comment: @ic0n, did you come right... has your question been answered? If so please mark this as resolved, by checking the tick. Tx.